# Why can't I launch PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I downloaded pycharm using snap, and I edited the pycharm64.vmoptions file. Then I wasn't able to launch the software, so I uninstalled it.

After that, I downloaded the pycharm.tar.gz file from the jetbrains website. I was trying to start pycharm by going to

> /opt/pycharm2019/bin/pycharm.sh

but I kept getting these messages

```
duck@duck-PC:/opt/pycharm-2019.3.1/bin$ ./pycharm.sh 
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated
in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : eg/eg/eg/license.jar 
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

I tried to reinstall it, but it didn't work.
I tried deleting all pycharm directories, but this also didn't work.
Is anybody able to help me?

Comment: Does '/opt/pycharm-2019.3.1/bin/eg/eg/eg/license.jar' exist? It says it cannot open it. Maybe have a look in pycharm.sh?

Comment: @tornado actually that is not the real directory I change it in here for clarification the file is in home/donloads/license/license .jar and yes it exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error messages was removed after deleting the following directory

> rm -d -r ~/.PyCharm2019.3

and after that reinstalling pycharm will make it work like a charm